# Is there a way to solve $\vec{y}=\vec{y}\times\vec{a}+\vec{b}$ for arbitrary vectors?

Tags: vectors

I have a vector equation, given by:
$$  
\vec{y}=\vec{y}\times\vec{a}+\vec{b}
$$
and I'm trying to solve it for $\vec{y}$. I've tried to take $\times\vec{a}$ of both sides and use vector identities to get me somewhere, but it's really not looking promising and it's got me wondering whether there actually is a way to solve this problem without prior information about $\vec{y}$, $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Crossing both sides with $\mathbf a$ gives \begin{align*}
\mathbf y \times \mathbf a &= (\mathbf y \times \mathbf a) \times \mathbf a + \mathbf b \times \mathbf a \\
\mathbf y - \mathbf b &= (\mathbf y \cdot \mathbf a)\mathbf a - (\mathbf a \cdot \mathbf a)\mathbf y + \mathbf b \times \mathbf a.
\end{align*}
Dotting both sides with $\mathbf a$ gives $$\mathbf y \cdot \mathbf a = \mathbf b \cdot \mathbf a.$$
Thus, \begin{align*}
\mathbf y - \mathbf b &= (\mathbf b \cdot \mathbf a)\mathbf a - (\mathbf a \cdot \mathbf a)\mathbf y + \mathbf b \times \mathbf a \\
(1 + (\mathbf a \cdot \mathbf a))\mathbf y &= (\mathbf b \cdot \mathbf a)\mathbf a + \mathbf b +\mathbf b \times \mathbf a \\
\mathbf y &= \frac{(\mathbf b \cdot \mathbf a)\mathbf a + \mathbf b + \mathbf b \times \mathbf a}{1 + |\mathbf a|^2}.
\end{align*}

Comment: You could also dot with $\vec{a}$ to start. Doing the dot and cross products then can be viewed as looking at the parallel and perpendicular components of $\vec{y}$ with respect to $\vec{a}$ which will identify the solution.

Answer (score 5):

I will drop the vector arrow. We can rewrite the cross product as
$$
y \times a=Ay 
$$
for some $3 \times3$ matrix $A$. Then, we can re-write the equation to
$$
y=y \times a + b \iff Iy=Ay+b
$$
with $I$ being the $3 \times 3$ identity matrix. Then you can re-write this as a  linear system
$$
(I-A)y=b
$$
and check for its space of solutions.